# Who has the knowledge of Brahma-Gyaan?

Tags: brahman, knowledge

Is it true that the  complete knowledge of Brahma-Gyaan is known only by tridev and tridevis ?

Comment: Thoda sa site par dhundh liya karo yaar. Itni faaltu cheejein puchh ke kaunsa maharath mil jaayega?

Comment: @Adiyarkku Pl Give link.